# How to apply aggregations(sum,mean,max,min etc ) across columns in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a datatable as,

```
DT_X = dt.Frame({
    
    'issue':['cs-1','cs-2','cs-3','cs-1','cs-3','cs-2'],
    
    'speech':[1,1,1,0,1,1],
    
    'narrative':[1,0,1,1,1,0],
    
    'thought':[0,1,1,0,1,1]
})
```

it can be viewed as,

```
Out[5]: 
   | issue  speech  narrative  thought
-- + -----  ------  ---------  -------
 0 | cs-1        1          1        0
 1 | cs-2        1          0        1
 2 | cs-3        1          1        1
 3 | cs-1        0          1        0
 4 | cs-3        1          1        1
 5 | cs-2        1          0        1

[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

I'm now applying a group operation summing of all the values across 3 columns as,

```
DT_X[:,{'speech': dt.sum(f.speech),
        'narrative': dt.sum(f.narrative),
        'thought': dt.sum(f.thought)},
        by(f.issue)]
```

It produces an output as,

```
Out[6]: 
   | issue  speech  narrative  thought
-- + -----  ------  ---------  -------
 0 | cs-1        1          2        0
 1 | cs-2        2          0        2
 2 | cs-3        2          2        2

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Here I'm manually giving the each field name and the aggregation function (dt.sum),as it is required only 3 columns i can easily carry this task out, but what if i have to work on more than 10, 20, etc etc fields?.

Would you have any other solution for it?.

Reference: we have a same kind of functionality in Rdatatable as :

```
DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=.(issue),.SDcols=c('speech','narrative','thought')]
```

Comment: You could use a dict comprehension, something like `{name: dt.sum(getattr(f, name)) for name in ['speech', 'narrative', 'thoughts']}`.

Comment: Yes. thanks for the hint. it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most functions in `datatable`, including `sum()`, will automatically apply across all columns if given a multi-column set as an argument. Thus, R's `lapply(.SD, sum)` becomes simply `sum(.SD)`, except that there is no `.SD` in python, instead we use the `f` symbol and combinations. In your case, `f[:]` will select all columns other than the groupby, so it is basically equivalent to `.SD`.

Secondly, all unary functions (i.e. functions that act on a single column, as opposed to binary functions like `+` or `corr`) pass-through the names of their columns. Thus, `sum(f[:])` will produce a set of columns with the same names as in `f[:]`.

Putting this all together:

```py
>>> from datatable import by, sum, f, dt

>>> DT_X[:, sum(f[:]), by(f.issue)]
   | issue  speech  narrative  thought
-- + -----  ------  ---------  -------
 0 | cs-1        1          2        0
 1 | cs-2        2          0        2
 2 | cs-3        2          2        2

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: On running the above code it's throwing an error: ```DT_X[:, sum(f[:]), by(f.issue)]``` TypeError: Unable to apply reduce function `sum()` to a column of type `str32`

Comment: So tried this out: ```DT_X[:, sum(f[:].remove(f.issue)), by(f.issue)]```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one of recommended solution by @Erez.

```
DT_X[:,{name: dt.sum(getattr(f, name)) for name in ['speech', 'narrative', 'thought']},
by(f.issue)]
```

and output:-

```
Out[7]: 
   | issue  speech  narrative  thought
-- + -----  ------  ---------  -------
 0 | cs-1        1          2        0
 1 | cs-2        2          0        2
 2 | cs-3        2          2        2

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Note: `f[name]` is exactly the same as `getattr(f, name)` but more compact.